# How to find all deprecated methods through "Inspect Code" in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I tried the following options and some questions from StackOverflow but it didn't work for me. I'm unable to find a deprecated section in Inspection results.

1. Analyze(from the menu) -> Inspect Code
2. Analyze(from the menu) -> Run Inspection By Name -> typed "Deprecated API Usage"

I'm using Android Studio 4.1 and targetSdkVersion & compileSdkVersion is 30.